# Vertically and horizontally align bootstrap 4 container column over background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, bootstrap-4

After digging around the web for about 5 hours the only result I got was each child of the column would line up horizontally.

I have included the nav bar as that some time interferes with it.

```
<header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Name</a>
      <!-- Collapse button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <!-- Collapsible content -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <form class="form-inline" action="/search">
            <input class="form-control bg-dark text-light mr-sm-2 py-1" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" required type="search">
          </form>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">One</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
          <!-- Right alignment needed -->
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/sign-in/"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sign in</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- HERE - Hero image -->

  <div id="intro">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <h2 class="display-4 mb-2">My website</h2>
          <hr>
          <h4 class="my-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h4>
          <a href="#">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light px-4 py-2">Action <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          </a>
        <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

CSS

```
html,
body,
header,
#intro {
    height: 100%;
}

#intro {
    background: url("via.placeholder.com/2000x1000") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
   color: white;
}
```

I have tried a range of things and deleted most of them but still have these attempts, I cleaned up the html though.

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Also tried d-flex solutions, justify solutions and others...

So I now believe it is something to do with bootstrap but I don't known.

Edit: Forgot to say, horizontally align it can be achieved with:

```
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

https://jsfiddle.net/Aorus/z3p4s0t9/1/

What you were missing was adding the following classes to your row;

- align-items-center ([vertical align class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment))
- justify-content-center ([horizontal align class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment))
- h-100 ([make the height 100%](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/))

Also set you're header, or any other parent, to height:100%.

```css
html,
body,
header{
  height: 100%;
}

#bg-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i350.photobucket.com/albums/q409/spawn_065/galaxy.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width:  300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Name</a>
      <!-- Collapse button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <!-- Collapsible content -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <form class="form-inline" action="/search">
            <input class="form-control bg-dark text-light mr-sm-2 py-1" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" required type="search">
          </form>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">One</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Two</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Three</a>
          <!-- Right alignment needed -->
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/sign-in/"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sign in</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div id="bg-container">

  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="image-container">
        Image
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</header>
```